# How to add new custom field to product custom option in magento?

Tags: php, magento

As per my question, I tried many times to add custom field to product custom option in magento. I want to add custom field value in database `catalog_product_option_type_title` this table.
Please help out of this query.
[I want to do as per image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSKvO.png)

Comment: you want to add custom field in admin with title or value?

Comment: Title already there, i want add value of that title in to database

Comment: you can use this example http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/how-add-custom-attributes-custom-options

Comment: I already use this example but didn't work.

Comment: I have also using this example and it's working perfectly please check and debug your code

Comment: Give me proper method, i already use this method but as per my side it didn't work. Can i send my code example to you?

Comment: ok send what you have tried

Comment: Select.phtml
 '<td><input type="text" class="input-text" name="product[options][{{id}}][values][{{select_id}}][css_class]" value="{{css_class}}"></td>'+

Comment: you edit only one file select.phtml?

Comment: option.php

'css_class' => $_value->getCssClass()

Comment: and you want to add field like this example http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/how-add-custom-attributes-custom-options  or anything else

Comment: in phpmyadmin add new field in this table catalog_product_option_type_value

Comment: and do not try this <?php

/* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */

$installer = $this;

$installer->getConnection()

    ->addColumn($installer->getTable('catalog/product_option_type_value'), 'details’, 'VARCHAR(128) NULL');

$installer->endSetup();

Comment: I want to add same as above link which did you send me.

Comment: because this script use to create field in this table

Comment: I already add "details" field manualy in database.

Comment: I am posting an answer read it carefully then implement it and remove your previous efforts

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. i will waiting for your answer.